# IIS URL Rewrite Http to Https, exclude single URL

Tags: http, iis, https, url-rewriting

I have several sites set up that are using a URL Rewrite to direct Http to Https.

All sites are setup with two sub-folders. Example:

1. http://www.example.net
2. http://www.example.net/abc
3. http://www.example.net/xyz

This is my current URL Rewrite Inbound Rule settings:

- Pattern: (.*)
- Condition input: {HTTPS}
- Check if input string: Matches the Pattern
- Pattern: ^OFF$
- Action Type: Redirect
- Redirect URL: https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
- Redirect type: Permanent (301)

All three re-direct to Https perfectly.

However, I need to exclude one of the sub folders from this rule and NOT re-direct it to Https (http://www.example.net/abc).

Could this be accomplished by modifying the existing rule condition? Or even better, by adding an additional rule or rule condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the existing rule and add additional condition:
[image]

Condition input: `{REQUEST_URI}`

Check if input string: `Does Not Match the Pattern`

Pattern: `^/abc`

With this condition, rule will exclude all URLs, which starting from `abc`. For example, these URLs will be excluded:

- /abc
- /abcdef
- /abc/xyz